# how to calculate this logarithmic function?

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

Im having trouble in graphing this log function: $y=\log _{1/4}\left|x^2-5x+6\right|$

I found the intervals: $(-\infty, 2)$, $(2,3)$, $(3,\infty)$

Should I just give $x$ values and find $y$ to graph this or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Use what you have computed:

On $(-\infty,2)\cup(3,\infty)$ the polynomial $x^2-5x+6$ is positive. So, the function is equal to $$\log_{1/4}(x^2-5x+6)$$

On $(2,3)$ the polynomial $x^2-5x+6$ is negative. So, the function is equal to 
$$\log_{1/4}((x-2)(3-x))$$

Now, apply to each of these the procedure to determine the main elements of the graph. For example [these](http://www.emathhelp.net/notes/calculus-1/drawing-graphs-of-functions/steps-for-sketching-graph-of-function/). Take the portions of those graphs lying on the relevant intervals and put the pieces together.